# View aspx - file in titanium?

Tags: visual-studio, titanium

I am working on a project in titanium. I would like to create part of this app in Visual Studio aspx page with ajax as a part of this page. Is it possible then to include it in titanium to view it and interact with it?

Comment: Possible, maybe, should you do it? Heck No. Two totally different and incompatible technologies. Just learn how to write it with Titanium, your users will thank you.

Comment: Plz Josiah Hester I was not asking wether it good or bad! I was asking if possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can view a web page using the Web View.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

Comment: I have tried that, but the only thing I se is the asp.net - files Code - behind text??

Comment: aspx files are rendered by a Windows Server, you have to have a windows server doing the leg work and converting these files to HTML in the background, you cant drop a *.aspx file in a webview, it must be a remote url.